# UseEffect not firing (NextJS) - CKEditor

Tags: next.js, ckeditor

I am trying to integrate **CKEditor** in my **NextJS** App and have the following code for the editor component (this solution was found in another SO post but is not working for me). The likely reason seems to be that UseEffect is not firing. When I do a console log inside UseEffect I cannot see anything in the console.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import styles from '../../styles/components/WriteBlog.module.scss';

const WriteBlog = () => {
  const [content, setContent] = useState('');
  const [editorLoaded, setEditorLoaded] = useState(false);
  const editorRef = useRef();
  const { CKEditor, ClassicEditor } = editorRef.current || {};

  useEffect(() => {
    editorRef.current = {
      CKEditor: require('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react').CKEditor,
      ClassicEditor: require('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic'),
    };
    setEditorLoaded(true);
    console.log('useEffect ran!');
  }, []);

  return editorLoaded ? (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <h1 className={styles.headingMain}>Create New Post</h1>
      <div className={styles.editor}>
        <CKEditor
          editor={ClassicEditor}
          data={content}
          onChange={(event, editor) => {
            const data = editor.getData();
            setContent(data);
          }}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  ) : (
    <div className={styles.editorLoading}>
      <h2>Loading Editor...</h2>
    </div>
  );
};

export default WriteBlog;
```

I just get a "Loading Editor..." screen that I have defined in the return statement.
I am importing the modules correctly as per the latest CKE documentation.

Why is the editor not loading / UseEffect not firing?

Answer (score 0):

This worked when I moved the code to the 'pages' folder of the application from the 'components' folder. Originally I was trying to import the editor as a component from components/blog/WriteBlog.jsx into the pages/blog/new/index.js file.

I have no clue why this solution works though. It seems to defeat the purpose of separating components and pages. Clearly I am missing something fundamental in NextJS. Any insights would be very handy for the rest of the project.